# GWT Cell Table Error

Tags: gwt

when I am doing this
     CellTable  table = new CellTable();
I am getting this error

The type CellTable is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like that : **CellTable
< T >**

Answer (score 0):

You should specify row datatype in constructor, see the [documentation](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTable.html); usage example is also provided there.